# dataGridView1 connect to my generic list?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

dataGridView1 I want to connect to my generic list. To do this I use the code below.

dataGridView1.DataSource = List;

(List is static)

But every time I want to update list generic dataGridView1 also get update
What should I do?

Comment: I'm trying to understand you, but your question isn't really in proper English.  If you don't want your GridView to update when data in your List is updated, don't use your List for data binding the GridView and for your updating (wherever that is occuring).

Comment: Do this right? dataGridView1.DataSource = null; dataGridView1.DataSource = _List;

Answer (score 2):

Use `BindingList<T>` instead; this provides lid change notifications (add, remove, etc). It also provides row-level notifications (for property changes), but only if your type correctly implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`; so implement that.

Re your "list is static" if you mean a `static` field, note that if you are. Using multiple threads you might run into trouble with that; I wouldn't do it that way, personally - but that is unrelated to the question.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
    class Foo
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
    }
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        using (var form = new Form())
        using (var grid = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill })
        using (var add = new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, Text = "add" })
        using (var remove = new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Top, Text = "remove" })
        {
            form.Controls.Add(grid);
            form.Controls.Add(add);
            form.Controls.Add(remove);
            var lst = new BindingList<Foo>();
            var rnd = new Random();
            add.Click += delegate
            {
                lst.Add(new Foo { A = rnd.Next(1, 6), B = "new" });
            };
            remove.Click += delegate
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach (var row in lst)
                { // just to illustrate removing a row by predicate
                    if (row.A == 2) { lst.RemoveAt(index); break; }
                    index++;
                }
            };
            grid.DataSource = lst;
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: static list<className> lst = new  list<className>(); dataGridView1.DataSource = lst; lst.add("AA","BB","CC"); lst.add("AAA","BBB","CCC"); dataGridView1 also apply changes... How??

Comment: @mah_85 `static BindingList<className> lst = new BindingList<className>();`

Comment: But note I still advise against `static` here. And note that to are individual property changes on individual rows, you still need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Please complete example check. How Connect ataGridView1 with lst? thx

Comment: static BindingList<className> lst = new BindingList<className>();  why BindingList?

Comment: i am lst.RemoveAll method. I can not use the BindingList

Comment: @mah_85 because `BindingList<T>` supports the necessary interfaces to make this happen.

Comment: @mah_85 then use `lst.Clear()`

Comment: @mah_85 I already told you; change List to BindingList, and RemoveAll to Clear...

Comment: Well I'm used to remove these codes.
var num = textBox4.Text;
lst.RemoveAt(s => s.Number == num);
Then again, does not answer.
I want to do I delete an item, not the entire list.

Comment: @mah_85 then why did you cite RemoveAll? Either way, that is trivially replaced with equivalent code. `List<T>` doesn't implement `IBindingList` / `IBindingListView` - thus it cannot provide UI updates. You are going to need to change a few bits of code to suit the BindigList api

Comment: How?? Possible to help with an example. please

Comment: @mah_85 I am on a portable device right now; no compiler - I'll try to add an example later, but I can't right at this moment